# What priority will as Task run as when the operation has the @MainActor decorator?

Tags: swift, concurrency, task, actor

I'm curious what priority the async `block()` in the code snippet below will run as when the Task's operation is marked `@MainActor`?

According to the `DispatchQueue` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html) the main queue always runs with a qos of `.userInteractive`. So I assume the Task's @MainActor operation will also run as `.userInteractive` - there's only 1 main thread after all.

But since we requested a custom priority for the `Task`, what priority will the async `block` run with?

```swift
Task<Void, Never>(priority: priority) { @MainActor in
    doStuffOnMainQueue() // .userInteractive
    await block()        // priority?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add `@MainActor` qualifier to the closure, that obviously runs on the main actor. But when it reaches `await block()`, that translates to “suspend the current actor (i.e., the main actor in this case) so it’s free to do other stuff and await the results of the `block()`.”

Regarding the question of what priority the `block()` uses, that depends on how it was declared. Assuming `block()` is just a closure that you passed to this method, then in my experience it runs with the `priority` that you supplied to `Task`, not the main actor. But there are lots of variables (e.g., you could specify `@MainActor` for that closure parameter, too; you could be calling some method running on some other actor; etc.), so we cannot get more specific without seeing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

But, bottom line, when you `await` something, the actor/priority of the awaited code is dictated by how you defined that, rather than the context of the code from which you called it.